# Populate ListBox with linq query - Value not getting set

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, listbox

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't set the value on the ListItems to ID? Value and Text both come out as DISPLAY_NAME

```
  lstSelected.DataSource = entities.User
     .Where(x => SelectedItems.Contains(x.ID))
     .Select(x => new ListItem { Text = x.DISPLAY_NAME, Value = x.ID })
     .ToList<ListItem>();

  lstSelected.DataBind();
```

Comment: Are you getting an empty list? or a populated list with blanks or garbage?

Comment: Dammit. Nevermind. It's the binding, not the linq. I didnt realise I needed to set DataValueField and DataTextField on the listbox. With listitems it should almost be automatic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties (or `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` if you are using asp.net)

```
lstSelected.DisplayMember = "DISPLAY_NAME";
lstSelected.ValueMember = "ID";
lstSelected.DataSource = entities.User
     .Where(x => SelectedItems.Contains(x.ID))
     .ToList();
lstSelected.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options (You are using both in a wrong way):

Set the `DataSource`, `DataTextField` and the `DataValueField`:

```
lstSelected.DataSource = entities.User
       .Where(x => SelectedItems.Contains(x.ID))
       .ToList<ListItem>();

lstSelected.DataTextField = "DISPLAY_NAME";
lstSelected.DataValueField = "ID";

lstSelected.DataBind();
```

Or instantiate `ListItem`s and add them to your `ListBox`:

```
List<ListItem> mySelectedItems  = entities.User
       .Where(x => SelectedItems.Contains(x.ID))
       .Select(x => new ListItem { Text = x.DISPLAY_NAME, Value = x.ID })
       .ToList<ListItem>();

foreach(ListItem item in mySelectedItems)
{
    lstSelected.Items.Add(item);
}
lstSelected.DataBind();
```